# CodeIgniter 4.0 shows me 404 error repeatedly

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I wrote the corresponding controller through the CodeIgniter document, but the page always shows me 404. My question is why exactly the same URL can not be displayed, and why this framework can only show me 404 pages. I remember that ThinkPHP has a complete running link for error reporting, and I can't see the problem with only one 404.

this is my url
http://localhost/index.php/demo/test

this is my Demo.php code

```
`<?php
use CodeIgniter\Controller;
class Demo extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        echo 1;
    }
}`
```

Demo. PHP files must be in the controller folder and there are no other directories, but CI reports 404 errors to me

Answer (score 0):

Its because they dramatically changed routes, you need to define in \Config\Routes.php and check their wiki as I am in process of refactoring my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Add a route with this

```
       $routes->get('pineapple','Demo::test');
```

ensure your server has mod_rewrite enabled and that you have .htacces file.

make sure that your base_url in app/Config/App.php is set with an ending slash on the url /